# Adding arrays as keys and values in NSDictionary/NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have already initialized two arrays named - `questionArray` and `correctAnswerArray`.

I want to add these two arrays in a `NSDictionary`/ `NSMutableDictionary` (the one more appropriate) such that the `questionArray` will be the value (each index of it) and the `correctAnswerArray` will be the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you chose NSMutableDictionary or not depends on if you want to change the data later on. Either way you can just change the following if you want a standard dictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:questionArray forKeys:correctAnswerArray];
```

**** EDIT ****

To retrive a value just do:

```
NSString *value = [dict valueForKey:@"KEY"];
```

or

```
NSString *value = dict[@"KEY"];
```

Comment: while taking the input can i put it inside a loop with the following loop count as the index number of the array? and retrieve the value in the same manner?

Comment: as i dont have a mac so i cannot try it out directly now but
can i jst run  loop say 

for(int i = 0;i<[correctQandA count];i++)
{
        NSLog ( @"%@", [correctQandA objectForKey: correctAns[i]]);
    }

Comment: Yeah you should be able to do that.